# Retrieve XML content from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have generated a XML, which I want to use it to query the SQL Server database.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<bank>
  <account>
    <ID>90898908877454</ID>
    <FirstName>Jonathan</FirstName>
    <LastName>Li</LastName>
  </account>
</bank>
```

C# method:

```
public List<BankAccount> bankInf(string content)
{
    List<BankAccount> list = new List<BankAccount>();
    // I want to take the XML content and use it to get all account transaction of the user (using his `ID`, `FirstName` and `LastName` fields)

    return list;// Return a XML of the result
}
```

My database looks like

```
bank
_____

ID   ----- 54857485
FirstName ------ Jonathan
LastName --------Li
Balance --------435.54
```

Comment: Is there any reason why your parameter is `string` rather than something like `XElement`? And if you want to retrieve "all account transactions", why would you return `string` instead of something like `List<Transaction>`?

Comment: I edited the code, But i don't want to use LINQ. Is there any other way i could do this ?

Comment: Well LINQ to XML isn't really LINQ - did you mean you didn't want to use LINQ to XML? Why not? What about XmlDocument etc?